# I have two classes and want to get a variable from one to the other

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have two classes. Draw and DrawGUI. In DrawGUI I have a JPanel. For my JUnit test I need to ask the class Draw for getWidth() and getHeight(). So my code is like the following:

```
public class Draw {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ColorException {new Draw();}

/** Application constructor:  create an instance of our GUI class */
  public Draw() throws ColorException { window = new DrawGUI(this); }

  protected JFrame window;

  public void getWidth(){
  }


}

class DrawGUI extends JFrame {
  JPanel drawPanel;

  public DrawGUI(Draw application) throws ColorException {
    super("Draw");        // Create the window
    app = application;

    drawPanel = new JPanel();
  }
}
```

So how do I implement getWidth? getWidth should return the width from the JPanel drawPanel

Comment: ```return window.getWidth();``` ?

Comment: @JornVernee I want getWidth from the JPanel DrawPanel and not the complete window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to change the weak type you're saving your `window` under:

```
public class Draw {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ColorException {new Draw();}

    /** Application constructor:  create an instance of our GUI class */
    public Draw() throws ColorException { window = new DrawGUI(this); }

    protected DrawGUI window;  // <- is now a DrawGUI

    public int getWidth(){
        return window.getPanelWidth();
    }

}

class DrawGUI extends JFrame {
    JPanel drawPanel;
    ...

    public DrawGUI(Draw application) throws ColorException {
        super("Draw");        // Create the window
        app = application;

        drawPanel = new JPanel();
    }

    public int getPanelWidth() {  // <- added method to get panel width
        return drawPanel.getWidth();
    }
}
```

There are other options. You could also just make a getter for the whole panel, but then you have less encapsulation.

---